# Create dynamic variable names inside of function (with self)

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt

Okay. So I searched a good while now and couldn't find another questions which describes my problem.

When I want to define a variable in Python, easy:

```
var = value
```

When I'm inside a class and want to define it for the whole class, easy:

```
self.var = value
```

In my special case I have a list which contains a few strings.
I want to create for each of these strings a variable, but for I am in a GUI function, I want to make it the above described way with self.

My problem now is, that when I try to put each string into `self.string` like:

```
list = [string, string1, string2]

for string in list:
    self.string = QPushButton()
```

Python does not compile the `string` in `self.string` but takes it literally. 
Therefore only three same variables all called `self.string` assigned with the method `QPushButton` are created.

What do I have to do to get three objects:

```
self.string = QPushButton()
self.string1 = QPushButton()
self.string2 = QPushButton()
```

To create some context: I want to create these buttons dynamically, each time a new item is added to the list, a new button is created. The list items are camera paths for an OpenCV video surveillance system.

Of course further arguments are used (setGeometry, setText, etc.) I just excluded them for readability.

My idea: It should be possible to pass an index into the for loop which then is added to the variable name: `self.string + index = ...` or something like `.format()`

Thanksalot

Comment: Use `self.buttons = []` `for string in list:` `button = QPushButton(string)` `self.buttons.append(button)`, later you can access: `self.buttons[i].some_method(...)`

Comment: Do not use `list` as the name of a variable, it is bad programming practice.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you very much. Why not make this the answer?

Comment: @eyllanesc Only for simplifying reasons ;)

Comment: Even though you have not noticed in the duplicate links of your previous question, and in which I have indicated it, there are a lot of questions similar to your question and answer them once more hiding other better questions.

Comment: @eyllanesc In this case sorry. I’ll do better next time.